# Find Solution set of $(\log_4x)^2+4\sqrt{(\log_4x)^2-\log_2x-4}=\log_2x+16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, logarithms, quadratics

My attempt :
$$\dfrac{1}{4}(\log_2x)^2+4\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}(\log_4x)^2-\log_2x-4}=\log_2x+16$$
$$(\log_2x)^2+16\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}(\log_2x)^2-\log_2x-4}=\log_2x+16$$
Let $a=\log_2x$
$$a^2+8\sqrt{a^2-4a-16}=a+16$$

Because this is fourth degree polynomials so I think this might not be the most efficient way to solve it.

Comment: There is something going on with the base $2$ and $4$, please edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $$a^2+8\sqrt{a^2-4a-16}=4a+64.$$

Now, we can use a substitution $a^2-4a-16=t^2,$ where $t\geq0$.